# Scrape HTML table with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the 11-column table off this URL using the rvest package: https://www.iexindia.com/marketdata/rtm_market_snapshot.aspx

So far I have been trying it using this code:

```
mrkt_snpshot <- read_html("https://www.iexindia.com/marketdata/rtm_market_snapshot.aspx")

my_data <- mrkt_snpshot %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill=T)
```

This is returning a list of 27 HTML tables on the URL as data frames, with some having up to 831 variables. I also used this:

```
my_data <- mrkt_snpshot %>%
  html_node("table.Ab7d468cb4fc14dedb1fcfeae435d33ac132") %>%
  html_table()
```

But this just returns an empty list.

I need help to pull just the table with 11 columns for each date for which the data is available. I also need to automate this to pull the data at the end of each day, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you the table you are looking for:

```
library(rvest)
mrkt_snpshot %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill=T) %>% 
  .[[24]]
```

Comment: Thanks Dominik! Another issue is getting previous days' data from the URL. Using this code I can only get today's data, but also need to scrape previous days' data, all of which has the same URL. Suggestions?